# Compute emgu video size manually

Tags: video, emgucv

I am using `emgu` to save uncompressed video. `VideoWriter("video.avi", 0, (int)FrameRate, frameSize, true);` The `0` value means that the saved video will be uncompressed, see [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Video_Files). Also, `FrameRate` aws set to 30.
The `Mat` file that is stored is:`var mat = new Mat(480, 640, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 3)`. For a stored video of `13994` frames, the property window says: `9.29 GB (6,449,164,288 bytes)`(windows). Now I am trying to verify the video size manually:

`640*480*3*13994= 12,896,870,400 bytes`, twice that window property returns.

Could you please cast some light on this?

**MediaInfo information**:

```
General
Complete name                            : name.avi
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
Format profile                           : OpenDML
File size                                : 6.01 GiB
Duration                                 : 7 min 46 s
Overall bit rate                         : 111 Mb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf56.36.100

Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : YUV
Codec ID                                 : I420
Codec ID/Info                            : 8 bit Y plane followed by 8 bit 2x2 subsampled U and V planes.
Duration                                 : 7 min 46 s
Bit rate                                 : 111 Mb/s
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Compression mode                         : Lossless
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 12.000
Stream size                              : 6.01 GiB (100%)
```

Thanks you.

Comment: Use a tool like **mediaInfo** to show us useful info like video codec, bit-rate, frame-rate, video-track size, audio-track size, etc...

Comment: @VC.One I have made the requested changes, I hope it is more helpful now.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll look into it properly later tonight but for now can you confirm whether or not that `emgu` uses 4 bytes (32 bit integer) per frame, even though your pixel type is 24-bit RGB?

```
Formula = Width * Height * 3 (rgb) * 21658 (frames) * 4 (ie: 32bit Int) / 8 (bits per byte)
```

Using the above formula I can get a close number...

```
640 * 480 * 3 * 13994 * 4 / 8 = 6,448,435,200
```

results:

```
on disk size    : 6 449 164 288 bytes (Windows) 
calculated size : 6 448 435 200 bytes (Formula) 
remainder size  :       729 088 bytes (possible AVI Header size as bytes?)
```

Just a quick one for time being, since I did not want to involve things like bit-rate etc. Normally file-size gives bit-rate or vice-versa. But in your estimation you won't know actual bit-rate until file is made so above is my best guess until I can think about it properly...

PS: MediaInfo can show you header size (in bytes) to confirm that last *remainder size* number.